# Reducing Complexity of Agent-Based Models

Tags: java, binary-heap, agent-based-modeling, mason-abm

I am developing an agent based model simulating the growth in-vitro of a cell culture.

I am using the MASON library (Java), but I guess by question could be applicable to different implementations.

Essentially, my agents are programmed to divide every 12 +/- 2 timesteps after their creation. Every time an agent divides, a new one is added to the simulation.

This leads to a very rapid growth of the problem's complexity, which quickly makes the simulation particularly slow.

In order to solve this problem, I decided agents should 'die' after *t* timesteps from creation.

However, MASON's schedule is built on a BinaryHeap which does not easily allow the removal objects (agents) once they have been added. My solution has been to set a boolean flag:

```
dead = false;
```

Which is set to true after *t* time-steps.

So

```
if(t == 50)
    dead = true;
```

I then begin my step method, that is the method called each time an agent is stepped, as follows:

```
if(dead)
    return;
```

However, I understand that simply accessing the object in the schedule is enough to slow the simulation down.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I could unset the agent or prevent it from being called?

Thanks,
Dario

Comment: According documentation you should be able to remove agent : `But you can also add and remove agents, or replace all the agents while the simulation is
running`

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [MASON documentation page 94](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/manual.pdf)

> If your agent is scheduled repeating, 
>   the scheduleRepeating(...)
>   method returned a sim.engine.Stoppable object. 
>   To prevent the agent from having its step(...) method ever called again, just call stop() on the Stoppable. 
>   This will also make the agent able to be garbage collected.